# PhantomJS gives Segmentation fault when running any js using command line

Tags: javascript, command-line, phantomjs

I have installed Phantomjs 1.9.8 on my Centos 6.5 server.

From the command line if I type

```
phantomjs -v
```

I get the correct version number returned, so I presume that it is installed ok.

However if I create a simple javascript file, using the most basic example from the phantomjs example:

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.exit();
```

and save this to a file `test.js`, navigate to that folder via command line and run

```
phatomjs test.js
```

I get

> PhatomJS has crashed... Segmentation fault.

Any idea what could be causing this or further tests I could run?

Comment: How much memory is allocated to phantom? There is a similar error reported on [Github](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11274) where phantom required 1GB of memory to run from command line.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, how can I tell how much memory is allocated to an application?

Comment: **Works here,** I installed it on a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the command `sudo apt-get install phantomjs` and it ran the `test.js` above fine producing the expected output with no errors.  Suggest trying a different computer or VPS.  VPS are very cheap nowadays, and can often be rented for pennies per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution - A key step of course is that you have to restart your apache web server to get this to work, I had forgotten this.

Leaving this up in case it helps anyone else stumbling along the same route